# jQuery .each() Alternative that Locates every nth-Matched Value on a UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, traversal, jquery-ui-slider, each

**Problem**: I'm working with a jQuery UI slider that uses very large values (range 0-140,000; steps 20,000), and I've modified a solution found elsewhere on Stack Overflow to add labels to the slider. However, that code (see below) adds a label for every number in the 140,000 range. *Is there an alternative to the .each() method that would only add a label for every x elements (I'm trying to get a label every 20,000 value)?* Or can someone recommend a more intelligent way to go about this?

**Javascript**:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 7,
    step: 1
})
.each(function() {

  //
  // Add labels to slider whose values 
  // are specified by min, max and whose
  // step is set to 1
  //

  // Get the options for this slider
  var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;

  // Get the number of possible values
  var vals = opt.max - opt.min;

  // Space out values
  for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {

    var el = $('<label>'+(i+1)+'</label>').css('left',(i/vals*100)+'%');

    $( "#slider" ).append(el);

  }

});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the end result is supposed to be, but I'll just point out that in a for loop you don't necessarily have to increment by 1.

Comment: @Snowburnt, since my slider has a minumum range of 0 and a max of 140,000 with steps of 20,000, I'm trying to get a slider with only 8 labels: one for 0, one for 20,000, etc, up to 140,000.

Comment: Why iterate over every one looking for every 20k one? why not instead only select every 20kth one? or increment i by 20k? `i+=20000`

Comment: @KevinB, that's what I'd like to do, just not sure which method to use or how to modify the for loop to achieve it

Comment: .... i literally gave you the modification in my comment.

Comment: @Marcatectura: for (var i=0; i<=vals; i+=20000)

Comment: min: 0,
 max: 7,
you have defined that means you will get labels at 7-0 at 7 lables

Comment: Snowburnt and KevinB thanks, I was trying to work the i+=20000 into the 'var el = ...' line, but now that I placed it correctly it's doing the trick. One of you should post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your actual range in your slider options:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 140000,
    step: 20000
})
```

Then use the `step` option as your increment in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i += opt.step) {...}
```

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjtxR/1/)**

And the resulting code:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 140000,
    step: 20000
}).each(function () {
    //
    // Add labels to slider 
    //

    // Get the options for this slider
    var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;

    // Get the number of possible values
    var vals = opt.max - opt.min;

    // Space out values
    for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i += opt.step) {
        var el = $('<label>' + i + '</label>').css('left', (i / vals * 100) + '%');
        $("#slider").append(el);
    }
});
```